# Inverter Oscillator Ground Return

Tags: pcb-design, oscillator, inverter, clock, ground-plane

I have a PCB design for a guitar pedal with a DSP chip processing some audio signals that would normally run off a 32768 Hz crystal, but part of the guitar effect allows the user to change the clock speed using a slide potentiometer. To do so, I am using the Schmitt trigger oscillator circuit shown in the Falstad schematic. My question is regarding ground return paths and shielding of the audio trace from the oscillator.

As shown in the PCB layout image, the oscillator circuit is entirely contained within a ground pour on the top layer. There is a solid ground pour on the bottom layer below the oscillator. There is an audio trace to the left and top (highlighted in yellow) and some audio traces off to the right (not shown). Additionally the DC power supply is off-screen to the right (also not shown). Given the design of the oscillator circuit, am I correct in thinking that there should be no high frequency ground return path from the oscillator that induces noise in the audio traces, and only the DC will have a ground return path off to the right? Should I include some via fencing to further shield the audio?

Notes: 2 layer board, solid (not split) ground plane. The location of the oscillator wrt the audio trace/dsp etc are determined by external requirements, namely the layout of the potentiometer and other elements on the user facing side of the guitar pedal.

[image: Falstad Schematic]

[image: PCB Layout]

Comment: Does the DSP use the 32768Hz from your inverter oscillator to multiply it with a PLL for internal use?

Comment: Yes, precisely. It's a Spin Semiconductor FV-1 for reference.

Comment: It may not answer your question, but it is unlikely that the PLL can stay locked to an unstable/noisy/jittery reference clock coming from an RC oscillator built with inverters. There could be a reason why it was using a crystal. While in some ICs a PLL can be used with internal oscillator, they are usually not such low frequency which require a large multiplication factor. I think the 32 kHz coupling to audio is the least of the problems, and it depends on the impedance on that audio wire too.

Comment: Understood. I have tested this using a breadboard version with a lead soldered to the clock pin and it seemed to work pretty well. The clock looks pretty stable on my oscilloscope, however I don't have a quantified phase noise. I'm sure there is a minimum recommended clock speed but I don't think I've reached it quite yet. Additionally a similar circuit, minus the potentiometer, is used on a few commercial guitar pedals as well, using the same DSP so I believe this solution could work.

Comment: Spinsemi explicitly says in their knowledge base you can use that kind of oscillator.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that as well.

Comment: Would you consider using a spare inverter CD40106 as output buffer for pin 8? It is unclear what this oscillator is driving...a variable load can change its duty cycle, or frequency slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Traces radiate mostly downwards/upwards (to their flat side).  So make sure you have solid GND under your oscillator, connected to the oscillator ICs with close Vias to the IC.

If you leave the GND plane you show without via fencing, the signals on the GND plane will (possibly) bounce back and forth until they find their return path. So do use via fencing.

You can also lave more space between the GND and the audio signal, there is no need to keep those two close, since you have GND plane underneath the audio signal. Leaving copper so close to the audio signal can make these "bouncy" signals on the copper decouple to the audio signal.

Using an oscilloscope, it might be easy to spot of the oscillation decouples to your audio signal. Example of one of my own projects, the I2C data decouples between the twisted pair of cables:

[image: decoupleExample]